# Not getting desired output in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a link in `quiz.jsp` to `play.jsp`. And in `play.jsp` i wanted to display quiz question and answers from the database but I am not getting it.
If any help then I would be very thankful.

Quiz.java

```
public class Quiz {
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String ans1;
    private String ans2;
    private String ans3;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

QuizRowMapper.java

```
public class QuizRowMapper implements RowMapper {

    public Quiz mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        quiz.setId(rs.getInt("idquestion"));
        quiz.setQuestion(rs.getString("question"));
        quiz.setAns1(rs.getString("ans1"));
        quiz.setAns2(rs.getString("ans2"));
        quiz.setAns3(rs.getString("ans3"));
        return quiz;
    }
}
```

QuizDaoImpl.java

```
public class QuizDaoImpl implements QuizDao {
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public void setTemplate (JdbcTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
    }

    public List<Quiz> getQuestion() {
        List questionList = new ArrayList();
        String sql = "select * from question";
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        questionList = template.query(sql, new QuizRowMapper());
        return questionList;
    }

    public void insertQuestion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

HomePageController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @Autowired
    UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;

    @Autowired
    QuizDaoImpl quizDaoImpl;

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute user use){
        return new ModelAndView("register");    
    }

    @RequestMapping("/insert")
    public ModelAndView successMessage(@ModelAttribute user use){
        if(use != null){
            userDaoImpl.insertData(use);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("success" ,"name", use.getuName());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView getUserList(@ModelAttribute user u){
        List<user> userList = userDaoImpl.getData();
        int len = userList.size();
        for(int i = 0;i< len ; i++){
            String userr = userList.get(i).getuName();
            if(userr.equals(u.getuName())){
                return new ModelAndView("quiz","name", u.getuName());
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView("register");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/userSign")
    public ModelAndView getUser(String name){

        List<user> userList = userDaoImpl.getData();
        int len = userList.size();
        for(int i = 0;i<len ; i++){
            String userr = userList.get(i).getuName();
            if(userr.equals(name)){
                return new ModelAndView("quiz","name", name);
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView("error","name",name);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/play.jsp")
    public ModelAndView getQuestion(){
        List<Quiz> quiz= quizDaoImpl.getQuestion();
        return new ModelAndView("play", "quiz", quiz);
    }
}
```

quiz.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>play quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome ${name}
    <a href="play.jsp">quizz</a>
</body>
</html>
```

play.jsp

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Being Java Guys | quiz </title>   
</head>  
<body>  
    <center>  
        <br /> <br /> <br /> <b>User  
         List | Being Java Guys </b><br /> <br />  
         <p>Question</p>
         <p> ${quiz.id}</p>
         <p>{quiz.question}</p><br>
         <c:forEach items="${quiz}" var="qz">
             <p> ${qz.id}</p>
             <p>{qz.question}</p><br>
             <p>${qz.ans1}</p>
             <p> ${qz.ans2} </p>
             <p>${qz.ans3} </p>
         </c:forEach>
     </center>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You should elaborate on what "Not getting desired output in spring" means, what is the *desired output* and what is happening right now.

Comment: @BackSlash I want the questions from the database to be displayed in in 'play.jsp' but I am not getting it. Thank you

Comment: I think that you're trying to show a list of questions in your play.jsp page but you are failing on traversing that list. Your quiz object is the complete list not a single one. You should use a foreach tag or something equivalent https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/

Comment: @RubioRic I have used <c:forEach> but still not getting I think I have a problem in RequestMapping in controller but couldn't find.

Comment: @RubioRic I am mapping request to play.jsp and returning the same play as a modelAndView.. Is it allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

In your play.jsp, you typed

```
${user.ans1}
```

Instead of

```
${quiz.ans1}
```

Then since you are returning a list object to play.jsp, you are to use jstl foreach tag to loop through the list

```
<c:forEach items="${quiz}" var="qz"> ${qz.question} ${qz.ans1} ${qz.ans2} ${qz.ans3} <br> </c:forEach>
```

And remember to add jstl taglib uri at the top of the page. That's this

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: thank you for the mistake. I have made it quiz but still not getting.

Comment: Isn't there an error message we can use as a guide?

Comment: I have done as if you said and again I am not getting. I think there is problem in my controller in requestmapping but I couldn't exactly find.

Comment: I am using play.jsp in request mapping and returning the same view through modelAndView is it allowed?

Comment: thank you so much but the problem later I found was in quiz.jsp  <a href="play.jsp">quizz</a> it must be only play not jsp

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put @ResponseBody in your /play.jsp endpoint... Add that that might fix your problem...

Comment: thank you so much but the problem later I found was in quiz.jsp  <a href="play.jsp">quizz</a> it must be only play not jsp